# Transform non-normal form dataframes to 1NF by creating new dataframes with unique keys

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I didn't quite figure how to formulate this question, suggestions to improve the title is welcome.

Let's start with my huge table which multiple props which are not in any normal form. I create this table out of multiple language specific datasets.

```
+-----+---------+--------+-----+----------+
| Key | Prop_A  | Prob_B | ... | Language |
+-----+---------+--------+-----+----------+
|   1 | Light   | Stone  |     | EN       |
|   2 | Medium  | Wood   |     | EN       |
|   1 | Leicht  | Stein  |     | DE       |
|   3 | Hard    | Stone  |     | EN       |
|   2 | Mittel  | Holz   |     | DE       |
```

I would squeeze them and extract the redundancy information in separate dataframes.
So the result should be something like that:

```
Example: with NF
+-----+---------+--------+
| Key | Prop_A  | Prob_B |
+-----+---------+--------+
|   1 | LIGHT   | STONE  |
|   2 | MEDIUM  | WOOD   |
|   3 | HARD    | STONE  |
+-----+---------+--------+
```

The values in uppercase represent the primary key of the property table with the discrete values

```
Example: Prop_A Table
+--------+---------+--------+
|  Key   |   EN    |   DE   |
+--------+---------+--------+
| LIGHT  | Light   | Leicht |
| MEDIUM | Medium  | Mittel |
| HARD   | Hard    | Hart   |
|        |         |        |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

My first idea was to group by `Key` and `Language` and then apply the properties (Prob_A,Prob_B) to a dictionary. I tried it with `groupby('key')[['Prob_A', 'Language']].apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).to_dict()`. However I failed always because I never got something out which comes close to my table above.

The second idea was grouping on two steps. First group on the keys and then group on the language and the properties itself. Collect the result in the list. 
The last idea was that group by key and Language and iterate over all rows. In the loop the values should be collected in a set for each property which holds the language information too. However I have no idea how the structure of the collection should look like that the result looks like above.

In also read some chapters in the pandas docs about multi index and categorisation, but it doesn't fit to my usecase. In the past I use pandas more for aggregation on numeric value and not for data transformation.

I have the feeling that I use the wrong tool (panda) for my problem. In my head the idea is rather clear but I can't see the solution with pandas.
Could you please give me some ideas how to solve this problem with panda or other suggestions?

My Demo DF looks like

```
lst = [["1",'Light', "Stone", "EN"],["2",'Medium', "Wood", "EN"], ["1",'Leicht', "Stein", "DE"],["3",'Hard', "Stone", "EN"],["2",'Mittel', "Holz", "DE"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns= ['Key','Prop_A', 'Prob_B','Language'])
columns = ['Prop_A', 'Prob_B']
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `dictionary` where each `key` is the column and the content is the property table for each column, then just modify your original dataframe. Since the dictionary was created based on the original, no keys will be missed:

```
columns = ['Prop_A', 'Prob_B']

dfs = {
    col:
    df[['Key', col, 'Language']].pivot(
        columns='Language', values=col, index='Key')
    for col in columns
}

dfs['Prop_A']

#         DE      EN
# Key       
# LIGHT   LEICHT  LIGHT
# MEDIUM  MITTEL  MEDIUM
# HARD    NaN     HARD

df_f = df.query('Language == "EN"')[['Key'] + columns].\
    apply(lambda x: x.str.upper() if x.name in columns else x).\
    drop_duplicates()

df_f

#   Key Prop_A  Prob_B
# 0 1   LIGHT   STONE
# 1 2   MEDIUM  WOOD
# 3 3   HARD    STONE
```

There is no `Hart` in `Prop_A` from the example

Comment: Thanks, take some time that I understand the way. However could you also post your source or check my update. Because I get different output.
dfs['Prop_A']
Language      DE      EN
Key                     
1         Leicht   Light
2         Mittel  Medium
3            NaN    Hard
```
df_f
  Key  Prop_A Prob_B
0   1   LIGHT  STONE
1   2  MEDIUM   WOOD
3   3    HARD  STONE
```